# Jmeter How to stop the execution of all threads when find error in thread

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter
I just wanted to stop the execution of all threads when find error in any of the threads.
[image]

I gone through many blogs and I used Action to be taken after Sampler error as Stop Thread and Stop thread etc.
Still I didn't see threads getting stopped in Jmeter GUI.
What to use if I want to see thread stopping when find any error while running threads.
Eg
Threads :500
Rampup: 5 Sec
If thread fail at 450 thread then I should see
#samples as 450 amd error % as 0.01(or something )in Summary report.
Is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if you run your test with 1 thread, when you have more than one thread you will run into the situation when there are several threads online executing Samplers and when the error occurs JMeter will either **ask** threads to stop or **tell** them to stop resulting in more sample results than you expect.

Also according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you're not supposed to be running your test in GUI mode, it's only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to test execution you need to [run your JMeter tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

However it doesn't explain the results you're getting, I wouldn't expect exactly 1000 sample results given your configuration so if you want to get to the bottom of the issue you will need update your question with test plan overview, .jtl file and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) contents.

Comment: Thank You for your reply.My problem solved as I run using non GUI mode.The threads stopped executing when it find any  error in the threads .U solved my issue :)

Comment: Hi, Can anyone clarify my doubt.